# How to use multiple datasets in amCharts Stock chart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I have two datasets and want to use them to display the line charts in amCharts Stock Chart. This is the fiddle. It only shows the data from the first dataset.

```
 "stockGraphs": [ 
    {
      "id": "g1",
      "title": "Graph #1",
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "valueField": "value1",
      "useDataSetColors": false,
      "valueAxis" : "axis1",


    }, 

    {
      "id": "g2",
      "title": "Graph #2",
      "lineThickness": 5,
      "valueField": "value2",
      "useDataSetColors": false,
      "connect" : false,
       "valueAxis" : "axis2"

    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a0p3vm8r/1/

I am sure there is a simple JSON config missing somewhere. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Why do you use two datasets for this? How about just merging the values into one dataset?

Comment: Here is the link for multidatasets - https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: here is the link for milisecond graph http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/YgsL7/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=YgsL7

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that need to be done in order to display graphs from the compared data sets.

1) Make the second data set compared by setting [`compared: true`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/DataSet#compared).

2) Set [`comparable: true`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#comparable) and [`compareField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#compareField) for the second graph.

3) Your fiddle code creates data for the second data set with "value1" as a value field, while graph `valueField` refers to "value2".

Here's your chart with all of the above applied:

https://jsfiddle.net/a0p3vm8r/2/

Comment: You did not get me i want to use multidata sets for milliseconds

Comment: just check multisets data graph i want to use it in milliseconds